# R code: Efficiency Issue

Tags: performance, r

I have a vector of length 14 and I would like to check in sets of 5 in this manner:

```
compare = c(rep(1,4),rep(0,10)) # Vector

g.test = matrix(0,5,10)
for (i in 5:14){
 g.test[,i-4] = head(tail(compare,i),5)
}
if (sum(colSums(g.test) >= 3 & colSums(g.test) < 5 ) > 0){yield = T}
```

I am running through the vector 
`compare[c(10:14)]` to `compare[c(9:13)]` to ... to `compare[c(1:5)]` and checking if any of it has a `sum >= 3` and `< 5`.

BUT, compare is just 1 such vector; I've 100,000 such vector of different permutations of 1's and 0's but all of length 14. running my code like that took my computer 100 seconds to run through. Is there a better way to do this?

- I'm actually running a simulation test for Texas poker. This portion of the code is used to check for incomplete straight draws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
g.sums <- rowSums(embed(compare, 5))
yield <- any(g.sums >= 3 & g.sums < 5)
```

100,000 iterations on my machine:

```
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.438   0.052   2.493
```